# Windows 8 cloned drive in 2nd computer

Tags: windows

I did the Windows 8 Pro upgrade machine w/ 64GB SSD. Finding 64GB not enough, I ordered a 128 GB SSD (Samsung 830) while planning to use CloneZilla to clone the Windows 8 OS to it.

I might try using the 64GB SSD (with the Windows 8 upgrade on it) as a boot drive in a backup machine.  I understand that I need to do some registry work to make it happy about the SSD 'transplant,' but I am worried about having to register the same activation key on 2 computers.

Am I at high risk of getting 'deactivated'?  Note that the backup machine is only used when primary computer is off.